# Golang operator &^ working detail

Tags: go, operators, bitwise-operators

I'm reading a Golang tutorial book at operator chapter, it says `5 &^ 11 = 4`, but this operator seems not so common so I can't understand immediately,

I try to guess its logic by list the binary form of the three number:

```
      5 = 0101
 &^)  11= 1011
 -------------
      4 = 0100
```

But I still can't understand it, can anyone explain how `&^` works?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mentioned in [Spec: Arithmetic operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)

> ```
> &^   bit clear (AND NOT)
> ```

So it computes the AND connection of the first operand and the negated value of the second operand.

Its name "bit clear" comes from what it does. Examined using it on two 1-bit value: if the second operand is `1`, it means to "clear": the result will be `0` regardless of what the first operand is. If the second operand is `0`, it means not to clear, and the result will be the first operand.

Its [Karnaugh-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) is:

```
A | B | A &^ B = A AND NOT(B)
--+---+----------------------
0 | 0 |   0
0 | 1 |   0
1 | 0 |   1
1 | 1 |   0
```

When used on integer numbers, the operation is carried out *bit-wise*, that is the 0th bit of the result will be using `&^` on the 0th bit of the first number and the second number; the 1st bit of the result will be using `&^` on the 1st bit of the fist number and the second number etc...

So basically the result of `A &^ B` will be the number derived from `A` by clearing the bits (setting them to `0`) marked by the ones in `B` (in `B`'s binary representation).

Comment: thank you, I'll mark it as answer after ten minutes, sorry I'm not graduate in CS  so these knowledge is not so  sufficient  (and I got hint by SO when asking this question will get downvote @@)

Comment: @yuyangJian Most of us aren't graduates in CS.

Answer (score 0):

It will not the second operand then and them. It's the same as offing the bits.

```
     5 = 0101
&^   11= 1011
-------------
     0101
&    0100
-------------
     0100
```